# How can I record mobile network traffic?

Tags: mobile-network, mobile-data, data-monitoring

I need to record edge/3g mobile traffic in pcap file. I can't find any working app for this. How can I do this?

Samsung Galaxy s3, root, cyanogenmod11.

Comment: [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526)

Answer (score 0):

There is a free app that can record the usage of network traffic in your android device. You can monitor network traffic usage using the [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture&hl=en) app and it saves as [PCAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/38626/how-can-i-read-pcap-files-in-a-friendly-format) file format. As in the description provided in the playstore link tPacketCapture works even on non-rooted devices and recorded data is stored as [PCAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/38626/how-can-i-read-pcap-files-in-a-friendly-format) file,

> - tPacketCapture does packet capturing without using any root permissions.
> - tPacketCapture uses VpnService provided by Android OS.
> - Captured data are saved as a PCAP file format in the external storage.

Comment: I tried already. It's not working on S3.

Comment: @Ric What problem do you have using the app?..does it not generate the PCAP file or whether you are unable to read the file..?

Comment: It's not generate pcap file.

Comment: @Ric found another app named sniffdroid have you tried this..https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.serious.sniffdroid