# How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?

Tags: applications, networking, internet, data-monitoring, processes

There are lots of discussion on how to see which app is requesting network connection. I have tried the following apps:

```
tcapturepacket
wifi monitor
connection tracker
```

However, none of them was useful. For example, for a short period of time, I uploaded a 30KB pcap file which can be viewed [here](https://packettotal.com/app/analysis?id=b12e54b2ab1e0c5ca0a2ad4df1f219e0). Still I haven't find out which app is requesting connection and to where it is trying to connect.

I also tried to look at `adb logcat`, but didn't find useful information. Maybe something has been missed here. Any guess?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have rooted phone, go for `nethogs` (for live monitoring) or `iptables` (to get statistics) commandline tools. Using VPN or Android stats based apps is the only possible non-root solution. Or refer to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/178024/218526) for a `logcat`/`dumpsys` based solution.

---

First of all, tracking a UID or PID of a network stream isn't straight forward because these aren't network related but OS related parameters. [Proposals](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1184) and [abandoned projects](https://github.com/HoneProject) do exist.

Android assigns a unique UID to every installed app just like every human user on Linux has a UID. So we can capture packets sent by a specific UID over the network interfaces to track the usage.

### TCPDUMP:

Now how we can capture network traffic? Most of the network sniffers use [libpcap](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html) family of system-independent libraries for this purpose. It supports **BSD Packet Filter (BPF)** for in-kernel packet filtering. Some popular utilities that use `libpcap` include `tcpdump`, `nmap`, `tshark/wireshark`, `dumpcap`, `nethogs` etc. Android app [Network Utilities](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myprog.netutils) and others also make use of `tcpdump`.

However UID info is not propagated through the [`AF_PACKET`/`PF_PACKET`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-packet/) channel that `pcap` uses at [**OSI Layer 2**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_2:_Data_Link_Layer). So what we can do here is to make use of network sockets (combination of IP and port) being created and used by an app. `netstat -tup` or `ss -tup` will show all network sockets with active/established connections. Both tools are available on Android (or you can get a static binary), `ss` is the newer one. **Socket vs. UID** information can also be directly read from `/proc/net/{tcp,udp}`. Android app [Netstat Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rinacode.android.netstatplus) works on same principle. This will provide Local Address (socket) being used by a process.

Once we know what sockets are being used by an app (UID), `tcpdump -i wlan0 src <IP> and port <PORT>` will dump the whole traffic originated from that process.
Similarly a remote socket (if not connected to by multiple apps) can also be used for filtering results.

**LIMITATIONS:**

However there are some issues with this approach:

- Android apps usually launch more than one process at a time in parallel i.e. **multiple PIDs working under same UID**. So we have to capture traffic from all processes.
- Apps keep on creating and deleting sockets. Keeping track of **continuously changing sockets** is almost impossible particularly when there are a large number of apps accessing network simultaneously.
- There is - though rare - possibility that local **sockets are being shared** by multiple processes on UNIX-like OS's. Remote shared sockets such as UDP/53 which is used for DNS resolution cannot be tracked for a single process. This further weakens the approach.

[**NetHogs**](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) traverses `procfs` and copes with the above limitations (though not always very successful):

[image]

### IPTABLES:

The above described shortcomings of a Layer 2 tool can be mitigated using [iptables `LOG` or `NFLOG`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html). **Layer 2** is just above the Physical Layer i.e. it's the last thing packets encounter before leaving the device. That's why, being at Data Link Layer and working at lower level of net stack, BPF is a kind of stateless packet filtering mechanism as compared to `netfilter` / `iptables` which works at OSI **Layer 3** (nearer to userspace programs). So `iptables` can also get information from TCP/IP stack (**Layer 4**). It filters packets based on their creator UIDs using module `owner` that [interacts with sockets](http://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/extensions/libxt_owner.c) to find packet ownership.

`iptables` writes to kernel log which can be read using `dmesg` or `logcat`. UID of an app can be obtained using some app or read from `/data/system/packages.list` or `pm list packages -U`.

```
# iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner <UID> -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix 'SNIFFER: ' --log-uid
# dmesg -w | grep SNIFFER
```

Output can be saved to a file and formatted using tools like `grep`, `awk`, `printf` etc. [Network Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.networklog) - though very outdated - works in similar way. [AFWall+](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall) is a firewall based on `iptables` that can log / notify an app's network activity when the app is blocked.

The only downside with this approach is that it cannot be used to sniff traffic from one process when there are **multiple processes running with same UID**. `iptables` can't capture packets based on PIDs. They decided [not to use `iptables` with processes](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34b4a4a624bafe089107966a6c56d2a1aca026d4) because the process is started before it is blocked/sniffed, and program could easily spawn a child process with new PID which would not be blocked / sniffed. Also PIDs are created and destroyed as quick as sockets are. So there is always room for traffic being leaked.

### QTAGUID:

`owner` module won't work for **incoming or forwarded traffic** because IP packets carry no ownership information. To measure per-app incoming / outgoing network usage, Android patched kernel to include [`qtaguid`](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/8468092ab618a65b6cde809ffceb9f18d2b9d02f) module. We can read statistics from `/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats`. With some shell scripting get live data usage since reboot:

[image]

However on Android 9+, `qtaguid` is being [replaced](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/datausage/ebpf-traffic-monitor) with [extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter#Extensions_and_optimizations) BPF (which is also planned to [replace](https://cilium.io/blog/2018/04/17/why-is-the-kernel-community-replacing-iptables/) `netfilter` framework in Linux kernel). Related: [Which process is responsible for capturing data usage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216959/218526)

### IPTABLES + TCPDUMP:

An alternate is to put the outgoing traffic from an app in an `NFLOG` group and later [tcpdump captures](https://sourceforge.net/p/libpcap/patches/59/) packets from that group:

```
# iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 30
# tcpdump -i nflog:30
```

This is to ensure that we get closer to physical layer when sniffing outgoing traffic. But it can still give **false positives** e.g. if packets are dropped / lost in routing tables. That's why [sniffers](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/36511/at-which-layer-does-wireshark-capture-packets-in-terms-of-osi-network-model) work at OSI layer 2. Or even better is to watch from outside e.g. using a proxy / VPN server or on a tethered PC or at router. But this won't capture traffic on per UID/PID basis.

### OTHER OPTIONS:

- Use diagnostic tools like `strace` to track `syscalls` related to network activity of a process. [force_bind](https://github.com/meebey/force_bind) and [tracedump](https://github.com/iitis/tracedump) also work on same principle. Linux kernel's [audit subsystem](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214229/218526) can be used for the same.
- Use [Network classifier cgroup](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.19/Documentation/cgroup-v1/net_cls.txt) with `iptables` [`NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CGROUP`](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.19/net/netfilter/Kconfig#1115) to sniff traffic from certain process(es).
- Use `Network Namespaces` to isolate processes and read data usage on per interface basis. [nstrace](https://github.com/jonasdn/nsntrace) works on same principle.
- If the intention is entirely to block traffic originating from certain processes, `SELinux` and `seccomp` can be used to restrict the processes' ability to create sockets by defining restricted `policies` and suppressing `syscalls` respectively.

Most of these are not straightforwardly viable options for Android and require advanced configurations.

---

### ANDROID'S APIs (NON-ROOT OPTIONS):

Some apps like [NetGuard](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard) use [**VpnService**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService) API of Android to block traffic at Layer 3 (TUN interface). The app can *"notify when an application accesses the internet"*. Per app capturing and tracking <sup>([1](https://www.mail-archive.com/netdev@vger.kernel.org/msg134466.html), [2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn#per-app))</sup> is possible using VPN API as Android makes use of `UIDs` and `SOcket_MARKs` <sup>([1](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-arch@vger.kernel.org/msg04829.html), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/include/FwmarkCommand.h#51))</sup> to control traffic in network Routing Policy ([RPDB](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-rule.8.html)), just before leaving the device.

Some apps like [NetLive](https://github.com/octohub/NetLive) make use of [**NetworkStatsManager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager), but it lags the real-time usage and *"does not update quickly enough"*, it's *"meant to provide historical data"*.

<sup>NOTE: I've no affiliation with any app referenced.</sup>

---

**RELATED:**

- [Restricting an app to only send internet traffic but not receive that back?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205831/218526)
- [Why network activity is detected from apps after firewall blocks them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214853/218526)
- [Capturing mobile phone traffic on Wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9555403/9165920)

Answer (score 4):

With [PCAPdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emanuelef.remote_capture) you can see the individual connections made by the apps. It's an open source tool developed by me which works without root (root is optional). It has lots of interesting features for users security and privacy, check it out

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and I got it to work in 5 minutes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to track which app performs connections to which server I recommend the app 

[Net Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.secuso.privacyfriendlynetmonitorapp) to you. It acts as a local VPN and is therefore able to detect all network traffic. Furthermore it shows which app has performed the network request (including remote host, ports, and even if the connection is plain or SSL/TLS).

Therefore if you use this app in combination with the capture tools you already mentioned in your question you should able to trace back each and every network connection.