# How to block TCP connections?

Tags: applications, networking, internet, superuser, ios

I have an app, a replica of a shooter game in Android. It is just for experimental use only, me and my friends are testing it. I need to block all TCP connections so I can test my security.

But its servers change IP addresses of the domain, so no matter how many ways I use to block the domain, user still get connection with the server.

Is there a way to only block TCP connection for an app? But only TCP connection, because my playing server is UDP server.

Can I block all incoming TCP connections as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to only block TCP connections for an app in Android?

Yes, if you have rooted phone:

```
~# iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 10275 -p tcp -j DROP
```

This will block 100% outgoing TCP traffic of app having uid 10275. You can get UID from file `/data/system/packages.list`.

To block only UDP:

```
~# iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 10275 -p udp -j DROP
```

Or to block both, don't mention any protocol.

> Can I block all incoming tcp connections?

`INPUT` doesn't work with `owner` module. Better is to just block outbound traffic, incoming is automatically blocked because traffic is initiated from client end i.e. your phone.
See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205831/218526) for details.

Also you can use `iptables` based firewall app like `AFWall+` or VPN based firewall like `Netguard` to block outbound traffic.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly