# how can i get the http sends requests from chrome just like from the network tab?

Tags: chrome-for-android, networking, developer-options, copy-paste, url

[image]

just like that .
pls do not mention network monitoring tools like wireshark

Comment: You can't do it from the mobile Chrome directly; you need to connect your device to the PC: [Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View network traffic requested by app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203868/view-network-traffic-requested-by-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

## On-device solutions

Use an app like

- [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture) (capture traffic like Wireshark)
- [NetCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.minhui.networkcapture)  (on-device Proxy with HTTPS decryption capabilities)
- [Packet capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture) - similar to NetCapture
- [HTTP Canary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guoshi.httpcanary)

## PC based solutions:

Use a proxy on your PC and redirecty all traffic through that proxy. There are a large number of Proxy that can be used like

- Burp Suite (Java)
- Fiddler (Windows/.Net)
- Charles Proxy (Java)
- mitmproxy

Comment: thanks for your  Great answer i think the PC based solutions doesn't fit for me ...
and how do you think i can get these requests in HTTP Canary  ? what filter should i use ?

Comment: @mina I would start with the [HTTP Canary user manual](https://github.com/MegatronKing/HttpCanary/wiki/User-Manual)

Comment: i am facing this now 
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214143/why-i-couldnt-monitor-traffic-from-this-page