# Why I couldn't monitor traffic from this page?

Tags: data-monitoring, certificates, https, debug, router

When I opened the capture log I found nothing from the page other than this when I first tried to visit it using http only, and then I get that security warning and i click proceed to unsafe anyway i still get nothing from that page 
although i have the root debugging certificate installed using 
HttpCanary

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clear the cache of the used app (the one you want to monitor). It might have save the old certificate and now does not accept the new one from HttpCanary.

Comment: @Robert i have tried it even with wireshark on pc and it still the same !!!
i tried to clear the "Clear the cache of the used app" but still didn't work ... btw the page certificate is invalid !!