# Which process is responsible for capturing (mobile/WiFi) data usage?

Tags: system-apps, data-monitoring

The problem is that it is broken for me. I customized quite a bit, specifically installing a firewall that uses root and disabling broadcast receivers and services in many Huawei and Google apps that came preinstalled. I guess one of these must be responsible for capturing how much data flows over each interface and from which app it originates, since the feature broke.

Which process (on any Android phone, I can probably find the equivalent once I know where to look) is responsible for doing this?

Comment: So your "settings -> data" isn't tracking right?

Comment: @rogerdpack Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataUsageController` (a component of Settings app) collects data from `NetworkStatsService` <sup>(1)</sup> which is part of Android framework i.e. `system_server` and depends on <sup>(2)</sup> `TrafficController` (a component of `netd` native service) which in turn uses [libqtaguid](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r48/libqtaguid/qtaguid.c) to tag network sockets on per app/UID basis. Previously `qtaguid` kernel module was used to track [tagged sockets](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/datausage/tags-explained) (by reading “/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats” <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r48/services/core/jni/com_android_server_net_NetworkStatsService.cpp#44))</sup>) which is being replaced with [eBPF](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/datausage/ebpf-traffic-monitor) framework. Now data usage will be available in a virtual filesystem (“/sys/fs/bpf/traffic_uid_stats_map” <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r48/core/java/com/android/internal/net/NetworkStatsFactory.java#129))</sup>).

[Network policy restrictions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r48/core/java/android/net/network-policy-restrictions.md) (Data/Battery Saver and Background Data <sup>(5)</sup>) and Data Limit/Warning are implemented mainly by `NetworkPolicyManager` and `NetworkManagementService`. At back end `netd` inserts/deletes `iptables` rules <sup>(6)</sup> to enforce restrictions in kernel space.

Both [qtaguid](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/8468092ab618a65b6cde809ffceb9f18d2b9d02f) <sup>(7)</sup> and [quota2](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/917596c2800a52c769d271bccc91b34da7bb59eb) modules are part of only Android kernel <sup>([8](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/datausage/kernel-changes))</sup> while `owner` is part of mainline Linux kernel.

RELATED: [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526)

---

<sup>**REFERENCES:**</sup>

<sup>1. The one we can access with `dumpsys netstats`</sup>
<sup>2. Through *NetworkStatsManager* / *TrafficStats* / *SocketTagger*, JNI *NetworkManagementSocketTagger*, *libcutils (qtaguid)*, *NetdClient*, Netd's *FwmarkServer* and possibly others</sup>
<sup>5. Can be read / set by `dumpsys netpolicy` and `cmd netpolicy`</sup>
<sup>6. Using modules *owner* and *quota2*</sup>
<sup>7. Based on *owner* module and depends on *socket* module</sup>

Comment: Woa, I had never expected such a detailed answer since it's very niche. Very glad I decided to ask the question anyway. Thanks a lot! I'm going to dive into this, but just catting `/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats` it looks like this is the usage data I'm looking for and it's just the settings data usage screen that is broken (I can parse csvs manually, no problem). Just gotta figure out over which period this tracking is and what all the columns mean (like `cnt_set`). I'll dive into this when I have some time in a few hours :)