# What is causing unknown network traffic on an Android phone?

Tags: networking, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro smartphone with Android 10 installed. Even when all apps are closed using the task manager, I see some realtime network traffic. It's not that much but it goes on all the time. This is also the case when not connected to Wifi (using 3G/4G).

Is there any way to check what specific apps/processes are consuming data?

[image: Network traffic]

Comment: Android OS itself makes connections e.g. to sync time and to check internet connectivity periodically. Also it's very rare to have all apps closed. Apps run services in background too, which might have network activity. Play Services are almost always online to fetch push notifications and doing other stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203868/how-to-view-network-traffic-requested-by-a-specific-app)

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yes, I already expected that the network traffic is caused by the OS/Android itself. Will look into the other question your referred to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before identifying and potentially vilifying specific apps, it is important to know that *any* app can schedule deferred background operations with the system.  This sort of background work can and often does include network requests, depending on the app.

My recommendation is to familiarize yourself with your system.  For example, inspect your account for any syncing settings.  A plethora of Google apps like to keep themselves up to date through Google Play Services.  I suspect that Redmi has OEM apps, or the OS itself, contributing to passive network activity as well.

If you would like to inspect which apps are sending packets, I suggest looking into network inspection tools such as those built into your router, or with programs like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Comment: Xiaomi's OS (called 'MIUI') was full of bloatware, I thought I removed all of that with ADB FastbootTools. Might have missed some bloatware or it's just the Android core that is constantly using internet connection. Going to give Charles Proxy a try.