# Android 10 - recording app network usage

Tags: applications, networking, android-10, data-monitoring, processes

On Android 9 or less, I use a shell script which continuously reads from `/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats` and greps by app UID to get app network usage. However, this method is deprecated on android 10: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/datausage/kernel-overview

Is there any other way I can get the same information? Or, how can I use the new eBPF network traffic tool to get this information?

Comment: See my answer to [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526). How to achieve this with eBPF is on my TODO list. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks!