# Where is the main website connection log?

Tags: logging

Is there a log/database of all the sites visited on my device, across all apps even in private modes? If not specific sites, just the domains/IPs connected to?

If so, where do I find it? How far does it go back? I would like to see it.

Comment: There is nos such think as a app overall browsing history. Webbrowsers do maintain a browser history but only if they are in non-private mode.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Robert is there no system-level log of connections, then? Not even just the domains connected to?

Comment: No main stream OS (Windows, MacOS, Android, iOS, Linux, ...) maintains a connection log. Having one is just a wet dream of politicians and people from police and intelligence.

Comment: @Robert oh, I guess that makes sense. I thought that Windows did maintain one though, as I believe that I've accessed one before in cmd. But I think it gets wiped every time it shuts down.

Comment: @Robert may I just confirm, that is true of all Android devices (ie. Sony, Samsung, Motorola etc)? I believe the OSs of each of these can be quite different from each other?

Comment: Related: [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526)

Comment: @user1829u2 Not sure about those Chinese brands but in general such a log or database would decrease phone speed and cause flash degrade therefore no manufacturer would implement something like this at free will, only if forced by a government would bring a manufacturer to implement this.