# how to find which process is continuously uploading data

Tags: adb, root-access, data-monitoring, termux, data

My phone seems to be suddenly uploading GBs of data at speed of 8+Mbps.
I cannot identify which direction app is doing this. But systems network indicator seems to show that is uploading data. Just not which app.

I even tried force stopping my frequently used apps while this happens to see if data upload stops. But i haven't been able to identify which app is the culprit.

Sometime the speed of upload reaches 20mbps and makes my phone stutter. What i can do find out enough app/process is transferring so much data.

I also tried installing https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drnoob.datamonitor

It also shows high speed of data transfer being happening. But it cannot identify which app is doing it. App specific usage stays low.

I have access to adb tools, root, as well as termux if that matters.

I tried using `nethogs` in termux but it didn't detect the process causing high speed data transfer.

Comment: Use `nethogs` with root: [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif I tried NetHogs with root. But its not able to capture the high speed datatransfer causing process.

Comment: Use `iptables` or `tcpdump` or both as explained in the linked answer.